# Elasticsearch - how to reflect the number of items in nested field to score?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am using Elasticsearch 2.x version.
The mapping of the data is as below.

```
"mappings":{
  "anchor_type": {
    "properties": {
      "image_url": {"type":"string"},
      "vocab": {"type":"nested"}
    }
  }
}
```

"vocab" consists of an array of `{string, float}` like,

```
[ {"human", 0.1}, {"dog", 0.3}, {"cat",0.5}]
```

What I want to do is, when "dog" is queried, I want the final score to be
0.3 / 3, that is, the score of matched term divided by the number of items in "vocab".

I made retrieving 0.3 working using `function_score` and `script_score`, but failing getting 3. I thought something like `doc['vocab'].value.size()` would work, but it doesn't...

Could anybody help me with this? Please...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [token_count](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/token-count.html) in the mapping for vocabs.
Use a multi field mapping and to a copy of the field , place the type as token_count. You can refer to this field for the size of array.